# How to call a PHP file using Windows Phone application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to create a simple login functionality in WP7 app using remote MySQL database using PHP as back-end. I have never used this in C#, so I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class to make a web request and get the response.

Here is a sample code on how to make a request and get response

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://someurl", UriKind.Absolute));
```

And the asynchronous response handler is here

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var response= e.Result; // Response obtained from the web service  
}
```

The above example works for any web service(it may be **PHP** or jsp or asp etc).

All that you need to do is to make a proper request and handling the response

Comment: I would recommend you to use HTTPWebRequest because WebClient will hit via URL and URL is limited to 1024 characters. So you must need to use HTTPWebRequest by Using POST HTTP Verbs.